# How to delete unused so library int Android gradle 7.3.1？ packagingOptions is invalid,not worked！！！

Tags: android

How to delete unused so library int Android gradle 7.3.1？ packagingOptions is invalid.not worked！！！

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude "lib/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so"
      exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libmp3lame.so"      
      exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/xxxxxx.so"
      exclude "lib/armeabi-v7a/libmp3lame.so"
      exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libmp3lame.so"    
  }
}
```